# How to remove written text - Python 3.6.4 Turtle

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I am new to Python 3.6.4 and I am creating an animation with the turtle. I am having trouble removing a written line of text from the screen. here is my code.

```
wn.bgcolor('purple')
time.sleep(1)
turtle.write("Welcome", font=("Lucida Sans Unicode", 16, "normal"))
time.sleep(1)
wn.bgcolor('black')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turtle provides some components to handle each other respectively.

In your case, it is a pen, a *RawTurtle class*, that can draw and clear itself.

Do you want to see the RawTurtle class? See the explanation in https://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html#turtle.RawTurtle

Here is some sample code that you can easily follow up.

```
# First, make a turtle object
# Second, Call a .getpen() method from the instance you created before.
# Third, Write Some Text, in my case, it is 'helloworld'
# Finally, clear what you write on the screen. 

import turtle
sample = turtle.Turtle()
pen = sample.getpen()
# 'Helloworld" text will show up on your screen
pen.write("Helloworld") 
# 'Helloworld' will be disapeared as you type it on console.
pen.clear()
```

Comment: Why both `sample` and `pen` when they are identical?  You don't need the call to `getpen()` as `sample is pen`.  OP specified Python 3 but you linked to the Python 2 documentation.  The `Turtle` class is fine here, a `RawTurtle` is used when embedding turtles into exisiting tkinter windows.

Comment: @cdlane I don't know what you want to ask. "Weridly" just want to cleanup text So I explain it as easy as I can.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the website https://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html for more

information, but my idea is that you should do

```
    turtle.clear()
```

Then you should redo the whole program withot the text.

I hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

You can `turtle.clear()` the whole screen, and then just redo what you did up to the point where you wrote the text; you can put a white square over where you put your text etc, but there's no "undoing" with the turtle.

The turtle module really just draws *pixels* onto a canvas. There's no internal info about what was done, just the canvas that now has a different color in the places that were drawn. In other words: it's just like if you'd draw with a pen on paper: The paper has a different color where the pen touched it, but to undo what you wrote, you need to get out your eraser and scrub exactly the points where you wrote. Or, you can get a fresh piece of paper and just start over, omitting the part where you wrote. In a computer, you'd often do that - drawing takes the computer very little time, and if you set the speed of the turtle to "fastest" and make it invisible, you will not even see that the screen was cleared in between.

The good news is that if you're at this point, you're probably pretty good at using the turtle – so it might be a good point to actually get used to ways to storing actions and redoing them later, so that you can implement the `turtle.clear()` and redo method I've mentioned above.

A beginner-friendly way of doing this would be something like:

```
actions = []

actions.append( ( "pen down", ) )
actions.append( ( "go to" , 10 , 8) )
actions.append( ( "write", "funny text") ) 
actions.append( ( "go to" , 8 , 2) )
actions.append( ( "sleep", 5) )
actions.append( ( "clear", ) )

for action in actions:
    if action[0] == "pen down":
        turtle.pendown()
    elif action[0] == "go to":
        turtle.goto(action[1], action[2])
    elif action[0] == "sleep":
        time.sleep(action[1])
    elif action[0] == "clear":
……
```

you get the idea.

Then, you can just remove the let's say third step (attention! Python counts elements starting from 0!) by doing a  simple

```
del actions[2]
```

As you can imagine, there's cooler ways of having a "command list" than trying to compare the command string to a set of commands every step, but they require a bit of knowledge about things like dictionaries and callables, so, I think this would be a nice start.

Comment: Python 3 turtle can undo and it's the easiest way to erase text that's been written to write anew.

Answer (score 0):

Python 3 turtle can undo actions.  You don't generally want `.clear()` as it removes everything a turtle did.  Usually, I use a dedicated turtle for text and park it where needed.  Then have it `.write()` and `.undo()` as needed:

```
import time
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

screen = Screen()
turtle = Turtle(visible=False)

screen.bgcolor('purple')
time.sleep(1)
turtle.write('Welcome', align='center', font=('Lucida Sans Unicode', 32, 'normal'))
time.sleep(1)
turtle.undo()

screen.mainloop()
```